# Can you fix a div and make it change opacity, size and position as you scroll with CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm not even sure how to search this question. But effectively I'm trying to figure out how this website is achieving this fixed opacity/size changing effect on their table: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial . If you scroll down you'll see the effect on the table. When you hover over it it pops out having the data more visible.

The only thing I can think of is using a fixed div that when scrolled past a certain point triggers a jquery UI event that shrinks while decreasing opacity and then an on hover event that reverses this effect.

Achieving this animation in the way I described above seems inefficient and I'm not sure if more (or all) can be done with CSS3. So basically can you achieve the effect shown on the page provided completely or almost completely in CSS3.

Also i looked at the source of the page and couldn't fish it out of the css and scripts they include.

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far. Haven't started on scrolling yet:

**HTML**

```
<div id="stuff">Blahblah</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( "#stuff" ).click(function() {
  $( "#stuff" ).animate({
    width: "20%",
      height:"20px",
    opacity: 0.4
  }, 1500 );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thed0ctor/1kx5jg1e/

Comment: What Code have you written yet so far ? post the fiddle

Comment: *"I'm trying to figure out how this website is achieving `x`"* followed by link to website isn't a proper problem statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily with a combination of CSS3 `transform` and a bit of Javascript / jQuery:

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hcwyth8n/2/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
#hanger {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    background-color: #00f;
    position: fixed;        /* Position fixed important */
    top: 10px; right: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s all;   /* Animate transitions */
}

#hanger.dim {               /* Style to make it appear dimmed */
    transform: scale(.75);  /* Make it smaller */
    opacity: 0.5;           /* Make it dimmer */
} 

#hanger.dim:hover {         /* To change back on hover only when it is dimmed */
    transform: scale(1);    /* Back to original size */
    opacity: 1;             /* Back to original opacity */
}
```

*Relevant jQuery Code:*

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {        /* When window scrolls, */
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {      /* Check if it scrolls more than 50 pixels */
        $("#hanger").addClass("dim");      /* Apply class dim */
    } else {
        $("#hanger").removeClass("dim");   /* Otherwise remove class dim */
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

.

Comment: This is great, had no idea about those properties. I'm trying to find see if there's a way of achieving the scroll effect without JavaScript. Parallax effects can be done without adding JavaScript event handlers but not sure about this effect

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code only:

---

> window.[scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)(function(){
>
> if (window.[scrolltop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) > selectedElement.[offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).top){
>
> selectedElement.[animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)({
>   transform: scale(.75),
>   opacity: .5
>   position: fixed
>   });
>
> }else{
>
> selectElement.animate({
>   transform: scale(.75),
>    opacity: 1
>   position: static
>   });
>
> }
>
> });

The links provided in the he pseudo code should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Note: jQuery's animation library performs badly. You would likely better off using transitions and a `setTimeout` or another animation libary

Comment: @ZachSaucier personally I would go with a css transition, not sure why you would need a setTimeout though... I was trying to keep it simple. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: The reason for the settimeout would be so that it doesn't try to stack transitions since a lot of scroll events fire.